# How to use AOP to protect method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

make custom Annotation like under code

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SingleShard {
    boolean isSingle() default true;
}
```

and use this Annotation in

```
public class AbstractDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SqlSessionTemplate sqlSession;

    @SingleShard
    protected void insert(String queryId, Object params) {
}
```

make AOP String class and use `@After("@annotation(com.test.sample.annotaion.ClearShardSelect)")`

```
@Aspect
public class ShardingAspect {
    @After("@annotation(com.test.sample.annotaion.ClearShardSelect)")
    public void testAfter() {
        System.out.println("call After !");
    }
}
```

`@After("@annotaion` doesn't work

when use like `@After("execution(* com.test.sample.dao.AbstractDAO+.*(..))")`

how to use @annotaion for protected method?

Comment: Did you register `ShardingAspect` as a Spring bean - by marking it as a `@Component` and package-scanning or explicitly in your `beans.xml` or as a `@Bean` in Java config?

Comment: @AdamMichalik yes when protected change to public it works

Comment: It seems to be that AOP can only be used to public methods ;